# Why PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER may be used to initialize a condition variable only when it is declared?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

> Since the PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER is actually a structure initializer, it may be used to initialize a condition variable only when it is declared.

**From**: Multi-Threaded Programming With POSIX Threads

**Question**: Couldn't understand the above quote.
It is just a macro, **why** can't I use it to initialize the condition variable on run time?
What has its being a *structure initializer* to do with anything?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because it is a structure initializer, you cannot use it to init the structure in a statement apart from its declaration.

It is defined on my system like so:

```
#define PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER {_PTHREAD_COND_SIG_init, {0}}
```

Expanded and used, we see:

```
pthread_cond_t p = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER; // << ok!
p = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER; // << compiler error =\
```

That is,

```
p = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
```

expands to:

```
p = {_PTHREAD_COND_SIG_init, {0}};
```

Comment: Since you've shown the code, I understand the meaning. Thanks, didn't know the "term" structure initializer. Very helpful.

Comment: @AnishaKaul you're welcome. note also that you *could* reinitialize it using C99 compound literals, provided of course it either failed initialization or has been destroyed, and your compiler supports C99 compound literals (*not* always C++ friendly). Here's the form: `p = (pthread_cond_t)PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;` -- which expands to `p = (pthread_cond_t){_PTHREAD_COND_SIG_init, {0}};`.

Answer (score 0):

For `g++`, use `-std=c++0x` parameter and your problem should be solved.